# Ключевое слово this для instance

Tags: java

Обязательно ли всегда для instance добавлять ключевое слово this? Например, есть такой код, где **power** - instance:

```
int work(int time)
    {
        return time * this.power;
    }
```

Ведь если убрать **this**, java всё равно поймет, что мы забыли дописать **this**, и результат будет тот же. То есть java сначала пойдет в stack, там **power** не найдет и потом пойдет в heap. Разница только в том, что java лишнее действие сделает.

Я всё правильно понимаю? Если да, объясните зачем писать **this**.

Comment: некоторые талантливые программисты не могут придумать идентификаторы для локальных переменных или параметеров функций и используют те же имена, что и у существующих членов класса

Comment: >Разница только в том, что java лишнее действие сделает

никаких лишних действий. Все это определяется во время компиляции

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы можно было безболезненно делать такие штуки:

```
void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power;
}
```

Т.е. чтобы обечпечить возможность доступа к свойству в любой ситуации, если я правильно понимаю, компилятор сам подставляет this куда надо. В яваскрипте, например, такой штуки с областью видимости нет, оттуда появляются всякие `var self = this`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` необязателен. Но удобен, например, чтобы отличать параметр метода/локальную переменную от поля:

```
public void Foo(string text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

Вообще хочу сказать, что если нет какого-то шаблона наименования полей (например, с подчеркиванием: `_field`), то использовать `this` весьма удобно: в дебрях кода глаз сразу распознает "тип": поле или локальная переменная/параметр. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал его использовать, разгрузите себе голову.

Comment: IDE выделяют локальные и глобальные переменные разными цветами, Intellij в частности.

Comment: Работа IDE -- несколько ортогональный вопрос.

Comment: ортогональный?)

Comment: Тот факт, что Идея это подсвечивает, никак не касается обсуждаемой темы. Употребление this -- отдельно, подсветка в IDE -- отдельно. Тем более что у автора может быть другая IDE, которая не подсвечивает локальные переменные/параметры/поля.